# Combinatorics - Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I am struggling a little to wrap my head around this combo problem. If I took 13 cards from a standard deck of playing cards, what would be the chance of having **exactly** one 10 within the 13 cards?

Comment: [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  If you have a box with $52$ balls, four of which red and the rest blue, what is the chance of having exactly one red ball when drawing $13$ balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{12}}{\binom{52}{13}}$

${4 \choose 1}$  is the choosing one card $10$

${48 \choose 12}$ is the choosing $12$ cards different from $10$

Comment: how to write C in latex?

Comment: I put this one $C(n;r)$

Comment: @KartikBhatia use \binom{}{} (ex: $\binom{n}{k}$)

Answer (score 1):

Total ways to select $13$ cards out of $52$ cards  is $52\choose{13}$ So these are the total number of outcomes.
Now we need favorable outcomes go for this $10$ you want now there are 4 ways to choose to get one $10$ One out of the spades,diamonds,hearts, clubs now for your Other 12 cards you have to choose you are left with $(52 - 4 = 48)$ cards to choose from which is indeed 
$48\choose{12}$ Now the final expression for getting Probability when each outcome is equally favourable is $$\frac{Favourable Outcomes}{Total Number of Outcomes}$$

$$\frac{ 4\choose{1}}{52\choose{13}}* {48\choose{12}} $$

Comment: Be very careful with saying that probability can be calculated as $\frac{Favourable Outcomes}{Total Number of Outcomes}$.  That is guaranteed **only** if the outcomes being described in the sample space are all equally likely to have occurred.  Stating that identity without such a disclaimer leads to confusion among beginner students incorrectly trying to use it in situations they shouldn't.

Comment: sorryy :) I will edit this part out ! I assume it before saying this formulae :) I should mention it